# CSS-clearfix: Why using "table" for the "display"-property?

Tags: html, css

I'm using these code for making wrapper-elements containing their floated children (instead of collapsing):

```
.wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Now I have seen code in which *table* is used as the value for *display*.

It's said that this is for "to contain the top-margins of child elements".

Full article here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

I've tinkered around with both variations (block, table) but I couldn't find any difference.

Can someone provide an example which shows the difference between using block or table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/4068027) SO question.

The `display: table` was needed on earlier days because of browser compatibility. The linked question explains why `display: block` is better than `display: table`